# OpenUrl return false and doesn't work after more than 5 times in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, openurl

here is my code to open another app:

```
string SchemeName = "ITSapp://";
                string param = "AuGeoStart:id="+System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+"Image=" + imgString + "&Latitude=" + currentLat + "&Longitude=" +  currentLong +
                    "&TargetLlatitude=" + targetLat+ "&TargetLongitude=" + targetLong +"&Angle=" + angle+"&Distance=" +distance+ "AuGeoEnd";

                string finalReqURL = SchemeName + param;
           

                NSString urlstring = new NSString(finalReqURL);

                NSUrl request = new NSUrl(urlstring);

                    bool isCanOpened = UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(request);
                    if (isCanOpened)
                    {
                        //bool isOpened = UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request);
                        bool isOpened =Task.FromResult(UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request)).Result;
                    }
```

here is my info.plist file

[image]

after 5 times this code not working and open url return false,
and CanOpenUrl return false

Comment: Is the urlstring same before and after 5 times? Is this problem happen in every deivces?

Comment: yes the urlString is the same , i can only test on iphone 11

Comment: Can you try to test on another device and I think it should not happen if  the urlString is the same. You can get the urlString  which does not work and open it directly in the browser to check if it works.